# Translate grammar production to Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, parsec, left-recursion

I'm trying to convert the following grammar production

```
callExpr:
    primaryExpr
  | callExpr primaryExpr
```

to a Parsec expression in Haskell.

Obviously the problem is that it's left-recursive, so I'm trying to parse it recursive-ascent style. The pseudocode I'm trying to implement is:

```
e = primaryExp
while(true) {
    e2 = primaryExp
    if(e2 failed) break;
    e = CallExpr(e, e2)
}
```

and my attempt at translating this into Haskell is:

```
callExpr :: IParser Expr
callExpr = do
    e <- primaryExpr
    return $ callExpr' e
  where
    callExpr' e = do
        e2m <- optionMaybe primaryExpr
        e' <- maybe e (\e2 -> callExpr' (CallExpr e e2)) e2m
        return e'
```

where `primaryExpr` has type `IParser Expr`
and IParser is defined as

```
type IParser a = ParsecT String () (State SourcePos) a
```

This however gives me the following type error:

```
Couldn't match type `ParsecT String () (State SourcePos) t0'
              with `Expr'
Expected type: ParsecT String () (State SourcePos) Expr
  Actual type: ParsecT
                 String
                 ()
                 (State SourcePos)
                 (ParsecT String () (State SourcePos) t0)
In a stmt of a 'do' block: return $ callExpr' e
In the expression:
  do { e <- primaryExpr;
       return $ callExpr' e }
In an equation for `callExpr':
    callExpr
      = do { e <- primaryExpr;
             return $ callExpr' e }
      where
          callExpr' e
            = do { e2m <- optionMaybe primaryExpr;
                   .... }
```

How do I fix this type error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`chainl1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html). `chainl1 p op` parses one or more `p`-s separated by `op`-s in a left-associative way. `op` returns a binary function which is used to combine the results of the `p`-s on both sides into a single result.

Since your grammar doesn't seem to have a separator, you can use `chainl1` with an `op` that just returns the combining function:

```
callExpr :: IParser Expr
callExpr = chainl1 primaryExpr (return CallExpr)
```

As to your `callExpr` implementation, I can spot two errors.

First, you use `return $ callExpr' e`, but `callExpr' e` is already a monadic value, so just `callExpr' e` would be correct.

Second, in `maybe e (\e2 -> callExpr' (CallExpr e e2)) e2m`, the default `e` should be monadic (or else how could we bind it to `e'`?), so it should be `return e`.

Comment: Could you explain why this combinator is needed? What makes it better than using `many` and then folding over the result? I'm still trying to learn the basics of parsing too.

Comment: It's probably somewhat faster, but I think it's mostly convention and communication of intent. I think parser combinators should generally resemble "pure" CFG notation as much as possible, and should minimize the amount of post-facto AST manipulation. Readers of our code should be able to see the grammar clearly and be not overly burdened by operational details. Left recursion is one point where we must deviate from abstract notation, so we try to encapsulate it in `chainl`.